# AngularJS - Close tile and load new view from model in ngRepeat directive AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem. I create a 3 tiles in browser and when i close  tile it must disapear and appear new tile in it place.

So in the top right i have a cross which must close the tile.

When I click first tile form the lict  to close moves to right and new appear on this place when was the old tile(and this is big bug in my app) and click on other tile do nothing.

And now I debbuging in browser code and in console have good data(in function close tile) but angular doing something wrong or maybe I. So in this function when I close tile, i remove it from list of object and add on this place new properties to new tile(from the restSlide).

So this is my directive:

```js
dModule.directive('activeMetro', ['$compile', '$http', '$templateCache', function ($compile, $http, $templateCache) {

var getTemplate = function (contentType) {
    var templateLoader,
        baseUrl = 'partials/tiles/',
        templateMap = {
            Club: 'club.html',
            Festival: 'festival.html',
            Theater: 'theater.html',
            Audition: 'tv.html',
            Seance: 'cinema.html',
            Sport: 'sport.html'
        };

    var templateUrl = baseUrl + templateMap[contentType];
    templateLoader = $http.get(templateUrl, { cache: $templateCache });
    return templateLoader;

};

var linker = function (scope, element, attrs) {
    var loader = getTemplate(scope.content.Type);
    var promise = loader.success(function (html) {
        element.html(html);
    }).then(function (response) {
        element.replaceWith($compile(element.html())(scope));
    });
};

return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: 'true',
    scope: {
        content: '=content',
        globalFoo: '=globalFoo',
        additional: '=additional',
    },

    controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', '$transclude', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude, $rootScope) {

        $scope.removeFromSlide = function (id) {


            if ($rootScope.additional.length > 1) {


                var slides = $rootScope.content;
                var restSlide = $rootScope.additional;

                var numSlide = $rootScope.slideNumber;
                var onSlide = $rootScope.activitiesOnSlideNumber;

                for (var i = 0; i < numSlide; i++) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < onSlide; j++) {
                        if (slides[i][j].Id == id) {
                            slides[i].splice(j, 1, restSlide[0]);
                            console.log(restSlide[0]);
                            restSlide.splice(0, 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
                $rootScope.content = slides;
                $rootScope.additional = restSlide;

            }


        };
    }],
    link: linker
}; }]);
```

removeFromSlide was the function which close my tile.

And now I have a page **result.html** :

```html
<div class="switch-tile-wrapper">
<div class="switch-tile" id="switch-tile">

    <active-metro  ng-repeat="item in content[0]" content="item" global-foo="globalFoo" additional="additional"></active-metro>
    </div> </div>
```

And code include with all type of tiles(this is template loading from directive which distinguish the type for tiles). The same code in all type of tiles i.e.

```html
    <div class="tile yellow-tile" id ="{{content.Id}}">
   <div class="activity-type">
          <span ng-click="removeFromSlide(content.Id)">X</span>
        {{content.Type}}{{content.Id}}  
    </div>
    <h4>{{content.Title}}</h4>
    <div class="activity-info">
        <p>G: {{content.G}}</p>
        <p>R: {{content.R}}</p>
        <p>Y: {{content.P}}</p>
        <p>K : {{content.Pr}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="activity-description">
        <p>{{content.Description}}</p> 
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm waiting for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Fix this bug:

In directive linker:

```js
var linker = function (scope, element, attrs) {
    var loader = getTemplate(scope.content.Type);
    loader.success(function (html) {

        element.html(html);
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    });
```